# How to access database created in sqlsrv with php after authentication?

Tags: php, sqlsrv

This

```
$serverName = "ROBOTO-PC\FREEPCADVICE";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"master");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName,$connectionInfo);

if( $conn )
{
 echo "Connection established.\n";
}
else
{
 echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

So But when I add a database like so:
[image: Microsoft SQL Express]

Then I don't know what I can do to access the SampleDB with PHP.  I can with MySQL but SQL Server seems to work different in it's access system with Windows Authentication.  Thank you for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to access to "SampleDB" but you are trying to access to "master"

```
 $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"master");
```

you need this

```
 $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"SampleDB");
```

I would recommend you to create a user and give just the permissions needed to access to that db, that way you will increase you database security

Comment: For some reason everytime I put it as SampleDB it says error connecting, but with  the master (or main area it doesn;t).  When I first set it up I made a simple password of Password01 for the root, so is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server

Comment: ]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. )